# How to add a section tag using jquery form builder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to add html `<section>` tag using jquery form builder?

please see this link for jquery form builder

http://formbuilder.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

Comment: Your question seems unclear.

Comment: I have edited my code, please see now

Comment: I don't think that's possible mate... You just need to add it manually.